# OnCollisionEnter in unity won't call function

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision-detection

I'm a complete unity novice. I want to make a simple scene where you have three lives and you lose a live if you collide with a cube. This is my script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class Lives : MonoBehaviour {

public Transform player;
public static int lives;
public Image live1;
public Image live2;
public Image live3;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    lives = 3;
    live1.enabled = true;
    live2.enabled = true;
    live3.enabled = true;

}

void Update () {
    DisplayOfHearts();
}

public static void Damage() {
       lives -= 1;
}

public void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col) {
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "cube") {
        Lives.Damage();
    }
}

public void DisplayOfHearts() {
    if (lives == 2) {
        live3.enabled = false;
    }
    else if (lives == 1) {
        live2.enabled = false;
    }
    else if (lives == 0) {
        live1.enabled = false;
    }
}
```

}

What happens is the player can't move through the cube but the amount of lives stays three. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Tell us about the game objects

Comment: The cube has a box collider and a rigid body. The "Is Trigger" function is not on. The player (camera) has a capsule collider with a trigger function which is also not on.

Comment: The documentation says that _Collision events are only sent if one of the colliders also has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached_. Is this the case ?

Comment: where is live script attached to?

Comment: Attach the Lives script to your player object, add a Rigidbody to it, uncheck the Kinematic property and it should work. The cubes you want to collide with only need to be tagged as "cube" and have a collider attached to them.

Comment: The cube has a non-kinematic rigidbody attached to it. The live script is attached to a canvas on which the lives are drawn.

Comment: I have added a rigidbody to the player object now with an unchecked Kinematic property. Now when I play the game, the player keeps spinning circles without a chance of walking to a cube.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [function OnCollisionEnter() not working unity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884352/function-oncollisionenter-not-working-unity)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you have attached the script to a wrong game object. The script and the collider must be attached to the same game object.

Unity methods inside a MonoBehaviour script (such as OnEnable, Update, FixedUpdate, Awake, Start, OnTriggerEnter, OnCollisionStay, etc..) only work for the game object which the script is attached to.

If you attach the script to another game object don't expect any of those to work. `Update` only works while *that* game object is active. `OnCollisionEnter` only works when a collision occurs on *a collider which is attached directly to that game object*. (it doesn't even work when a child has the collider instead of the actual game object where script is attached to)